# Encrypted/Secure Contact form plugin for WordPress

Tags: forms, security, encryption, wordpress, contact-form

I'm looking for a plugin for WordPress that will send my form information to an email address. However, I need the information to be securely sent. Just wondering if there is a plugin that can encrypt the information being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Any plugin will work over SSL. You just need an SSL certificate on your site. You won't be able to encrypt the email being sent, but you can then connect over SSL to check the email from your email client.